# My webpage is being framed with a 5 - 10 px border for some reason

Tags: html

Ive been having this issue accross a few projects im working on.

im sure its a basic issue and ive tried looking for answers but to no avail.

the code for the page in its entirity is:

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssbin/default.css" type="text/css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
        </header>

        <nav>

        </nav>

        <section>


        </section>

        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: #B3BDE6;
}

header {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #020C36;
}

nav {
    height:100px;
    background-color: #7A8FE6;
}

section {
    height:500px;
    background-color: #2B314D;
}

footer {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #020c36;
}

body, header, nav, section, footer {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

the webpage below shows what im talking about:

http://virtualharrogate.co.uk/template.php

in google chrome the page is framed, im not sure if this happens in every browser but i need to rectify the issue for chrome if nothing else...

Im asking why the borders there (as im obviously missing the point of something somewhere) and how to fix the issue?

ive tried styling the page with css properties `width: 100%; & height: 100%;` but still nothing.

thanks in advance

Comment: `body { margin : 0; }`? What am I missing?

Comment: "Im asking why the borders there (as im obviously missing the point of something somewhere)"

Comment: Ah, okay. As Abhisek's pointed out, this is a "just cuz" item, (keeps the document from crashing into the window chrome) though easily gotten rid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because by default `body` has `margin:8px`.

Here is the default stylesheet - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

Just add a `margin:0;` styling to correct it.

And you should use some sort of css reset before applying custom css. Thats the right way to go about stuff.

Check out [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/). It offers that plus a lot more, including IE6+ compatibility/fallbacks etc.

Comment: Nice updated answer as well... Many thanks for the information... im using the reset from the 960 grid and didnt understand the importance of it all before...

in the hope you might get something out of this ... i found this website quite insightful and usefull www.codiqa.com

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last line of your CSS:

```
body, header, nav, section, footer {  border: 1px solid black; }
```

This is adding a 1px border around ALL of those elements. Try removing body from that line.

Answer (score 0):

just use `body {margin: 0;}`  or `body {margin: auto;}`